# OpenCL MFC static application

Tags: mfc, windows-xp, opencl

I am building some MFC application which use opencl. Can somebody tell can I run opencl mfc program on PC which doesn't have installed AMD APP OpenCL SDK? Is there a way to build static mfc OpenCL application? I am using windows xp and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to merely run the program (running exe) ? or you want to develop/debug and build as well ? What kind of hardware you have ?

This is applicable if you are using AMD GPU/CPU

1. To merely run, make sure you have the latest AMD CATALYST DRIVER installed:
   http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx
2. To program using Visual Studio and Link MFC Libraries 
   a. Download AMD APP SDK http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx
3. Download AMD GDEBUGGER for debugging latest is 6.2 (very useful)
   http://developer.amd.com/tools/gDEBugger/Pages/default.aspx
4. Now you are all set, run some samples from the OpenCL samples directory where AMD APP is installed,
5. After the install, do the following Make sure to include $(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\include for header files Library Directory : $(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\lib\x86 or x86_64 depending on your bitness to your  OpenCL program.

HTH